# Lightning e.force:createRecord won't take RecordTypeId

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript

I'm trying to make a simple component for my home page which creates a record with a specific record type. Every time I try it, it uses the default record type instead of the intended. I've made a lot of components before with this function but never specified recordTypId. I've read the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:createRecord) and I'm at a bit of a loss as to why its not working with me.

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <lightning:card title="QUICK LINKS">
        <div class="slds-p-around_medium slds-grid">
            <div class="slds-col"> 
              <div onclick="{!c.redirectToNewItTicket}">
                  <img src="{!$Resource.quickItTicket}"/> 
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    redirectToNewItTicket : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('redirectToNewItTicket start');
        var createRecordEventItTicket = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
        createRecordEventItTicket.setParams({
            "entityApiName": "Help_Desk__c",
            "recordTypeId " : "012o00000003hMC"
        }); 
        createRecordEventItTicket.fire();
        console.log('redirectToNewItTicket end');
    }
})
```

I have verified the RecordType Id is correct. I used this code to ensure it is:

```
Schema.SObjectType.Help_Desk__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('IT').getRecordTypeId();
```

Any ideas? I'm thinking I'm missing something basic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have an extra space in the `recordTypeId` attribute so that it is "recordTypeId " and not "recordTypeId".  That's why it's not recognizing it as a valid parameter.

Comment: ah frick. Didn't even notice that. Thank you! It works!